# Issues in Play framework Server when I start using su deploy -c "play start"

Tags: linux, shell-scripting, hudson

I have play framework server and Im doing Automation using Hudson,

When I start the play server using su deploy -c "play start" it's fine the logs are getting updated and server is started.

The same command I'm using in shell script which is in Hudson, the command is executed but Play server is not getting started

'deploy' is one of the user to start and stop the Play server.

Can you anyone please help me

Note: As I don't have permission add new tags I couldn't add the tag 'playframework'

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the - option to su, as in `su - deploy -c "play start"`.  The - makes the su use the environment of the new user, instead of the previous user.  It is likely that paths and other options are not set up right when you don't run using the environment of the deploy user.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying complete path for your `'play'` binary in shell script if its not present in `PATH` variable, that might be the problem.